# Available space for pci cards on an IBM xseries 345

Tags: hardware, pci, ibm-xseries

The research lab where I work has been offered a bunch of IBM rack-mountable servers for very little money. The hardware is a bit outdated but it would suit our needs perfectly -- **If** we can fit one of our customized PCI cards into one of them.

I [looked around](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-58359) but just can't find any information on how much space is available for PCI cards. They have been referred to me as "IBM xserie 345" [sic], but I believe they meant "xSeries 345".

Do you have any link to official documentation that can help me? I need to know exactly how big a PCI card must be to fit into a server.

Comment: Are you asking for the maximum size PCI card that will fit?  If you think that a card you want to use is too big, you're better off measuring one and asking that question.

Comment: @gWaldo, yes, but I'd rather have a precise answer from an official document rather than a binary 'fits/doesn't fit' answer from a SF user. It's helpful to justify the money for the purchase.

Comment: Help me to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kind of backwards but here is a doc that shows a full length PCI card can fit into a 345

http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?infotype=an&subtype=ca&appname=redbooks&htmlfid=897/ENUS103-206

and another doc states that "Full-length PCI cards are 107mm (height) X 312mm (long)."

Answer (score 0):

If it's a standard size PCI card (such as a add-in card for a desktop for extra USB, Soundcard, NIC, etc) it should be fine.  If it's larger, "it depends".

Provide dimensions.

Comment: This is not an answer. I need a spec that says 'the server can fit cards of lenght X" so I can show it to management and justify the spending. I can tell you the dimension, you will tell me 'yes' or 'no' and then what do I do with that?